# How to deploy large nodejs package to AWS Lambda?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am trying to deploy a simple script to AWS Lambda that would generate critical css for a website. Running this serverless seems to make sense (but I cannot find any working examples).

The problem is with package size. I am trying to use https://github.com/pocketjoso/penthouse. When I simply `npm install penthouse` suddenly the package size is over 300MB. Size limit on Lambda is only 250MB and it will not upload.

Is there any way to solve this? Perhaps download penthouse on the fly? If so, is there any example?

Performance is not so critical in this case as it would be called only a few times a day by an automated process.

Comment: Perhaps using a CDN will help? Although it's nothing to do with `penthouse` in particular, it's more to do with the rest of the `node_modules` you have in your project. You can check the bundle size of `penthouse` here: https://bundlephobia.com/result?p=penthouse@2.2.2

Comment: That's right. I am new to nodejs, however how I understand it is that `penthouse` is dependent on `puppeteer` which includes chromium binaries and that makes the package grow in size.

Comment: I would say just use a CDN. https://unpkg.com/browse/penthouse@2.2.2/

Comment: have you thought about Lambda Layers? This article gives a good explanation - https://medium.com/harrythegreat/build-aws-layers-lambda-serverless-js-42cd6d17b155

Comment: Yes, Labda Layers were the answer. I had to use optimized chromium layer and force penthouse to install withnout chromium binaries.

Comment: @Tomage could you please share the details on how did you resolved this? Thanks!

Comment: @CarlMichaels Basicaly create 2 layers. One is chromium, you can use this: https://github.com/shelfio/chrome-aws-lambda-layer. The other one is Penthouse - you need to install it yourself and import as layer. It internaly uses Puppeteer and installs it with chromium - you dont want that. Set ENV variable PUPPETEER_SKIP_CHROMIUM_DOWNLOAD = true, when set, Puppeteer will be installed without chromium and Penthouse would be small enough so it could be imported as layer. Than use chromium from first layer https://github.com/pocketjoso/penthouse/blob/master/examples/custom-browser.js

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the bundle size of the package (https://bundlephobia.com/result?p=penthouse), it doesn't appear that your issue is primarily with the `penthouse` package. 
Although I cannot say for certain, I think it's mainly down to the size of your other dependencies.

Nevertheless, seen as this isn't a critical system and will be accessed a few times a day via automation processes, you can reduce the size of your `node_modules` folder by using a CDN.

There are a number of services which allow you to do this, I have primarily used `UNPKG` and `jsDelivr` in the past as they appear to be reliable with minimal-to-no downtime.

I lack the required detail from your question regarding which technology you're specifically using and the extent you can go to in order to achieve your desired result, but there are a few options you can choose:

- Utilise `webpack`'s externals configuration:
  https://webpack.js.org/configuration/externals/
- Use a CDN library loader such as: https://www.npmjs.com/package/import-cdn-js
- Or https://www.npmjs.com/package/from-cdn
- `loadjs` is another option: https://github.com/muicss/loadjs
- `scriptjs` https://www.npmjs.com/package/scriptjs

I don't know much about `penthouse` but with `scriptjs`, I assume you can achieve something like this:

```
var penthouseScript = require("scriptjs");

penthouseScript("https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/penthouse@2.2.2/lib/index.min.js", () => {

  // penthouse related code

  penthouse({
    url: 'http://google.com',
    cssString: 'body { color: red }'
  })
  .then(criticalCss => {
    // use the critical css
    fs.writeFileSync('outfile.css', criticalCss);
  });

});
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't see how is this relevant to AWS Lambda function. My website has to be absolutely independent to the lambda script. All I want to do is send a request to lambda script with website and css urls as parameters and it has to return critical css styles.

Comment: Thanks, will give it a try!

Comment: Just as I thought. It gives me "errorMessage": "document is not defined". I suppose that is because it is not executed in a browser. Thats what that puppeteer dependency is for. Will have to do it another way.