# Node Crtical/Penthouse in AWS Lambda

Tags: node.js, lambda, puppeteer, serverless, critical-css

Since uploading files to `AWS  Lambda` has 250MB limit, how can I setup a node project and use `Critical`? Mainly dont have issue with the package but its dependency `Puppeteer` that is using chromium. If  I will use other than puppeteer, how can I make Critical to not use the `puppeteer` binaries? I'm pretty new to AWS and nodejs.

Comment: Pretty sure this is a duplicate question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59945088/how-to-deploy-large-nodejs-package-to-aws-lambda

Answer (score 0):

As in the duplicated question comment - you can simply reduce the size of your node_modules by using a CDN such as unpkg, jsDelivr, etc.